# Is there a method in Python to generate arrays automatically, where I can access these arrays in the same program?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on a program that determines the time between multiple transports for several persons. For example, person_1 is carrying on one day 5 objects and I need to find out, how many objects they transported on the same time.

```
from datetime import datetime

format = '%H:%M:%S'
dateArray = ['2021-01-02', '2021-01-02','2021-01-03']
timeArrayBegin = ['11:00:11', '01:04:11', '11:05:11']
timeArrayEnd = ['12:04:00', '12:07:00', '12:12:00']
allDates = []
sameTimeArray = [0] * (60*24)

#fill allDates
if not allDates:
    allDates.append(dateArray[0])

for p in range(1, len(dateArray)):
    if dateArray[p] != dateArray[p - 1]:
        allDates.append(dateArray[p])

h=0
for i in range(0, len(timeArrayBegin)):
    if dateArray[i] == allDates[h]:
        gleichzeitig = datetime.strptime(str(timeArrayEnd[i]), format) - datetime.strptime(timeArrayBegin[i], format)
            
        difftozero = datetime.strptime(timeArrayBegin[i], format) - datetime.strptime('00:00:00', format)
        total_secondsdifftozero = difftozero.total_seconds()
        diffzerominutes = int(total_secondsdifftozero // 60)

        difftofull = datetime.strptime('23:59:59', format) - datetime.strptime(timeArrayEnd[i], format)
        total_secondsdifftofull = difftofull.total_seconds()
        difffullminutes = int(total_secondsdifftofull // 60)

        for v in range(0, len(sameTimeArray)):
            if (v >= diffzerominutes) and (difffullminutes > v):
                value = sameTimeArray[v]
                value2 = value + 1
                sameTimeArray[v] = value2

        else:
            h = h + 1
            print(str(dateArray[h]))

    for z in range(0, len(sameTimeArray)):
        if sameTimeArray[z] != 0:
            print(sameTimeArray[z])
```

If you run this code, the terminal print out the date and 1 and 2's. In this example:

```
2021-01-02
1
1
1
[...]
2021-01-03
1
1
1
1
1
2
[...]
```

Is there a method to get these 1 and 2's into a separate array (or list), so for each day I get an array with these counters?

What if I want to have this not only for days but also for a device. Example:

```
deviceArray = ['device1','device1','device2']
allDevices = []

#fill allDevices
if not allDevices:
    allDevices.append(geraeteArray[0])

for o in range(1, len(geraeteArray)):
    if deviceArray[o] != deviceArray[o - 1]:
        allDevices.append(deviceArray[o])

j = 0
h = 0

for i in range(0, len(deviceArray)):
    if deviceArray[i] == allDevices[j]
       if dateArray[i] == allDates[h]

       # rest of code

       else:
           h = h + 1
           print(str(deviceArray[j]) + " " + str(dateArray[h]))
    else:
        j = j + 1
        print(str(deviceArray[j]) + " " + str(dateArray[h]))

    for z in range(0, len(sameTimeArray)):
        if sameTimeArray[z] != 0:
            print(sameTimeArray[z])
```

Comment: You need to provide a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then clarify the output you need for some example input. Also, you seem to be confused about how to consume a range

Comment: it is good to see your effort, but would be much more helpful to follow this guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace

```
    for z in range(0, len(sameTimeArray)):
       if sameTimeArray[z] != 0:
           print(sameTimeArray[z])
```

with

```
result = [element for element in sameTimeArray if element != 0] # <-- list comprehension
print(result)

# Output 
[1, 1, 1, ..., 1]
```

`result` holds all the values you want.

---

Edit to answer your question in the comments:
Of course you can store your data linked to the corresponding date. I would suggest to use a dictionary for that:

```
h = 0
results = {}
for i in range(0, len(timeArrayBegin)):

    # rest of your code

    # print(str(dateArray[h])) <-- is not needed anymore, instead the current date is used as a key for the dictionary:
    results[dateArray[h]] = [element for element in sameTimeArray if element != 0]

print(results)
# Output
{'2021-01-02': [1, 1, 1, ..., 1], '2021-01-03': [1, 1, 1, ..., 1]}

# Beautifying the output
for date, counts in results.items():
    print(f'{date}: {counts}')

# Better output
2021-01-02: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...]
2021-01-03: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,...]
```

Comment: The output definitly looks better than mine before, but can I then also somehow access the individual arrays. For example, give me all the results of day 2021-01-02?

Comment: Yes, of course. I updated my answer show you how you can do that.

Comment: Yes, this is what i wanted!
But can I add a device to the "Better output" next to the date and the counter in the dictonary? So if I declared an extra array in the beginning with deviceArray=['device1','device2'] and let it go in another if query. 
I edited it in the question for better visualization.
So that the output will be something like this:
Device1 2021-01-03: [1,1,1,1,1,2...]

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You have 2 useful options here, either you use the string `str(deviceArray[j]) + " " + str(dateArray[h])` you already generated for your edit as the dictionary key instead of just the date. Since dictionary keys can also be tuples (in fact any immutable [see documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), your second option is to use something like `('device1', '2021-01-02')` as your key.